# ajax access code behind method not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm trying to call a function from codebehind in ASP.NET for VB.
Using chrome debugger, it is giving me an HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error. I already enabled ISAP-dll.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     try{

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'LabelDesign.aspx/DivideNumbers',
         data: { a: 10, b: 2 },
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
             $("#result").html(data.d);
         }

     }
     )
     }
     catch (err) {
         alert(err);
     }

     </script>
```

HTML markup:

```
<div id="result">Result</div>
```

and the codebehind:

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
 Public Function DivideNumbers(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
    Return a / b
 End Function
```

My ascx file is contained in a subfolder.

Comment: A 500 is not useful by itself. Have you tried enabling full debugging info, via your web.config, and see what the details of the error are?

Comment: `Public Function DivideNumbers(..` `As ???`

Comment: how to you debug in web.config? that is the only error i found and shown in the chrome debugger.

Comment: In chrome you should be able to view the response of the request (I think by double clicking on it) and it'll show the html of the response and ultimately the error/exception thrown. Another thing you could just do is run locally and step through the code, this way it'll throw the exception in VS and you'll be able to get the error message from that. (You also might want some validation on your DivideNumbers method, could easily throw a divide by zero exception)

Comment: i add a try catch and no error msg was show. when debugging,the code hit till success and it reached end of catch.no error was shown.the debug mode shows
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:52128/webform/Tools/LabelDesign/LabelDesign.aspx/DivideNumbers
version: 35
when i click on the link provided it my browser url changed but i am still on the same page and i right click and inspect the element again. 
then error message changed to 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)